# Вывести строки из файла которые чаще всего повторяются по айди

Tags: php

Всем привет, помогите сделать вывод строк из файла в популярном порядке. 
Т.е. вывести 5 строк у которых АЙДИ повторяется больше к примеру в текстовом файле есть записи...
1540453963|ЛОГИН|ТЕКСТ|АЙДИ|ИП|10:52|КОМУ|

допустим их 15 но из этих 15-ти есть 3 у которых одинаковый АЙДИ, тогда вывести эту строку с таким же АЙДИ.

Что то на подобии Рейтинга (Топа записей).

Сделал пока вывод только последних...
Вот так:

```
$a=file("news_text.txt");
$c=count($a);
$p=0;
$outputs.="<table border=0 cellspacing=0 align=center><tr>";
$nn=0;
for($i=$c-1;$i>=0;$i--) {     
$n=$c-$i; if($n<=$p*6 || $n>($p+1)*6) continue;
$nn++; 
$x=explode("|",$a[$i]);
$outputs.="<td align=center width=130 height=130>$x[3]</td>";
}
$outputs.="</tr></table>";
```

Comment: заводите массив. например `$counts=array();`. Идете по строкам файла, получаете id, делаете `$counts[$id]++` (ну там с всякими проверками на isset и т.п.). Потом сортируете этот массив по получившимся в нем количествам и выводите нужные строки. Как вариант, если памяти достаточно, делаете не ++, а складываете в массив сами строки, так что бы $counts[1540453963] указывал на массив строк именно с этим id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочитать файл в массив, сгруппировать по ID, отсортировать и выбрать срез *(5-ть элементов)*:

```
$filename = ''; // Путь к текст.файлу
$result = [];

foreach (file($filename, 6) as $line) {
    $id = explode('|', $line)[0];
    $result[$id][] = $line;
}

usort($result, function($a, $b){ return $b <=> $a; });
$result = array_map(function($a){ return $a[0]; }, array_slice($result, 0, 5));

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, но это решение такое же как я на фоячил, делает тоже самое.. А нужно что б по считало строки в которых повторяется Айди и потом вывести только те 5 строк которые самое больше повторяются... Выше писал что то на подобии Топ 5 записей или рейтинг...

Comment: @ДенисМилюков дак оно так и работает - собирает массив популярных строк. Проверка реализована по первому сектору _(я думал, что именно первый сектор это ID)_. Если нужна проверка по АЙДИ, то в цикле после эксплода замените ключ 0 на ключ 3.

Comment: Точно я даже не увидел что идет выборка по первому значению строки, спасибо вам большое)

Comment: А не подскажешь как можно теперь с помощью этого скрипта который вытаскивает айди, вытащить инфу из другого файла где айди идет первым типо так: АЙДИ|ЛОГИН|ТЕКСТ|КОМУ|  .... И чтоб все вытаскивалась принадлежащему айди. Добавил к твоему решению цикл чтоб вывести 8 записей.

Comment: Вот так $nn=0; for($i=0;$i<=7;$i++) {$nn++; $x=explode("|",$result[$i]); $out.='Строка - '.$x[3].' ';}

Comment: @ДенисМилюков ну вот в таком виде, как сейчас в моём ответе, оно и будет искать по первому сектору. А если нужны все записи, то уберите в конце функцию array_slice(). Или же если нужны 8 популярных вместо пяти, то замените 5 на 8.